# Cropping a thumbnail with a Genesis child theme

Tags: genesis-theme-framework, post-thumbnails

I'm a little bit lost right now. I'm developing my first Genesis child theme and I want to change the entries on the archive pages. I've found that WordPress offers a way of cropping images so I added this image size to my **functions.php**:

```
add_image_size( 'archive_image_size', 880, 300, TRUE );
```

In the **archive.php** I'm using the code like this:

```
/** Add the featured image */
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header' , 'featured_image_background_with_comments', 4);

function featured_image_background_with_comments() {
<div class="featured-archive-image">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'archive_image_size' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('No comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php 
}
```

My expected result is:
Width: 880px, Height: 300px, width is shown 100%, height is cropped (as the image is 2500 × 1407).

Actual result:
Width: 533px, Height: 300px, image is resized instead of cropped

Is there any mistake in my code or does this come from something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uploading a new image and seeing your code work. The issue is that cropping does not work retroactively - so it does not affect old images. There is a plugin - I haven't tried it, but it comes recommended - to update the older images to fit your new image sizes: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/